# Why is View that uses subset lookup table generating 5x more results than view using larger lookup table?

Tags: sql-server

**Goal**: I need to create a View that uses a different subset lookup table than the regular lookup table I already have. I only need 6 rows in the subset lookup table, but it needs a new column for a spanish translation.

**Problem**: The View is returning many more results than it should be.

**Summary**: 
I have 2  Views.
One of them is using a lookup table with hundreds of rows.
One of them is using a lookup table with only 6 rows. The view using this smaller lookup table somehow has 5x the amount of results(3,000 vs 15,000). How is this possible?

**What I've tried**: I've tried many variations of the tables and the views to come to this finding. It doesn't matter what values I look for in the SELECT statement. The only thing that makes the difference is using the smaller lookup table actually makes the views results larger.

```
SELECT slt.Name as Specialty,
s.ProviderName as ProviderName
from Database.dbo.some_table s
left outer join Database.some_other_table so on sa.randomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.third_table tt on tt.thirdrandomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.Smaller_Lookup_table slt on slt.SPECIALTY_ID = tt.SPECIALTY_ID
```

VS

```
SELECT llt.Name as Specialty,
s.ProviderName as ProviderName
from Database.dbo.some_table s
left outer join Database.some_other_table so on sa.randomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.third_table tt on tt.thirdrandomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.Larger_Lookup_table llt on llt.SPECIALTY_ID = tt.SPECIALTY_ID
```

Original Lookup table:

[image: DB Table Original/Larger]

Smaller Lookup table:

[image: DB Table Smaller]

Comment: You might have duplicates on `specialty_id` in the small lookup table. You can try : `select specialty_id from Small_Lookup_Table group by specialty_id having count(*) > 1`and see if it returns something.

Comment: @GMB , I tried looking for distinct values. It went from 15,000 results to 12,000. However, the result should actually be 3,000... so something is still wrong. It definitely has something to do with the lookup table as far as I can tell, because when I use the smaller lookup table it increases the number of results for the View

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your joins must be returning more than one row. The easiest way to find out which is to build up to the final query by executing these queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from Database.dbo.some_table s;
```

then join to the first one

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from Database.dbo.some_table s
left outer join Database.some_other_table so on sa.randomfield = s.randomfield;
```

then join to the second one as well

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from Database.dbo.some_table s
left outer join Database.some_other_table so on sa.randomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.third_table tt on tt.thirdrandomfield = s.randomfield;
```

then join to the third one as well

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from Database.dbo.some_table s
left outer join Database.some_other_table so on sa.randomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.third_table tt on tt.thirdrandomfield = s.randomfield
left outer join Database.Smaller_Lookup_table slt on slt.SPECIALTY_ID = tt.SPECIALTY_ID;
```

Once you've done that, you'll know which join is causing the extra rows, and you then can investigate the ON clause predicates for that table.

Comment: I tried this, and it was the join about the lookup table. When I create a smaller lookup table, it always ends up making the View have 5x more results, as compared to using the larger lookup table. This seems very counter intuitive.

Comment: Is SPECIALTY_ID unique in the Smaller_Lookup_table? If not, it'll give you extra rows. If so, then that won't happen.

Comment: Another option would be to not use LEFT OUTER JOIN to smaller lookup table. Instead use OUTER APPLY to a query that uses a TOP(1) to ensure that it matches only one row.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using inner join and it got rid of all of the unnecessary "duplicates." It looks much better now. I figured I didnt need SPECIALTY_ID to be NULL so that's why I switched to inner join. I'll look up the OUTER APPLY, I haven't used that before.